# How can i solve the following recurrence, T(n) = 1 if n = 1, otherwise T(n) = 2T(n/2) + logn ,exactly for n a power of 2?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, recurrence

[recurrence is here!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/72nJt.png)

Can someone please help me?

I know the first step is:

```
n = 2^i
T(2^i)=5T(2^i/2) + lg(2^i)
T(2^i)=5T(2^i-1) + lg(2^i)
define t(i) = T(2^i)
t(i)-5t(i-1)-lg(2^i)
```

im not very good with LOGs, can someone guide me through?

Comment: `lg(2^i)` is `i lg(2)` (which is just `i` if `lg` is the base-2 logarithm).

Comment: Put the recurrence in your question, the question should be self-contained.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a math question, not a programming question.

Answer (score -1):

`T(n) = 2*T(n/2) + lg(n)`

```
 = (2^2*T(n/2^2) + 2*lg(n/2)) + lg(n)

 = 2^3*T(n/2^3) + 2^2*lg(n/2^2) + 2*lg(n/2) + lg(n)

 ...    ...    ...

 =  2^i*T(n/2^i) + 2^(i-1)*lg(n/2^(i-1)) + 2^(i-2)*lg(n/2^(i-2)) + .. + 2*lg(n/2^1) + lg(n)

 =  n*T(1) + 2^(i-1)*lg(2) + 2^(i-2)*lg(2^2) + .. + 2*lg(2^(i-1)) + lg(2^i),  where n = 2^i

 =   n*1   +  (2^(i-1) + 2*2^(i-2) + 3*2^(i-3) + ... + (i-1)*2 + i*1)

 =   n   +  (2^(i+1) - 2 - i)    .... (1)

 =   n  + 2*n - 2 - lg(n)

 =   3*n - lg(n) - 2
```

where we can show (1) as follows:

```
  S  =           2^(i-1) + 2*2^(i-2) + 3*2^(i-3) + ... + (i-1)*2 + i*1  (3)
2*S  = 2^(i) + 2*2^(i-1) + 3*2^(i-2) + 4*2^(i-3) + ... + (i)*2          (4)

(4) - (3) => S  = 2^(i) + (2^(i-1) + 2^(i-2) + 2^(i-3) + ... + 2) - i
                = 2^(i) + 2*(2^(i-1)  - 1)/(2-1) - i  
                = 2^i + 2^i - 2 - i   
                = 2^(i+1) - 2 - i
```